# Bitbucket Pipelines error whilst building an application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, polyfills, bitbucket-pipelines

since this morning I'm encountering an error in the build process of my React application using Bitbucket Pipelines. Nothing has changed to my applications other than a few tweaks that has should not trigger this error.

When I try to build my app locally I don't get any errors whatsoever. Beneath you can find the error NPM throws in Pipelines.

```
+ npm run build-debug
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.9
npm info using node@v4.6.0
npm info prebuild-debug webplayer@0.1.2
npm info build-debug webplayer@0.1.2
> webplayer@0.1.2 build-debug /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> node scripts/build-debug.js
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'promise-polyfill' in /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/firebase/app
npm info webplayer@0.1.2 Failed to exec build-debug script
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.16-coreos-r1
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build-debug"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! webplayer@0.1.2 build-debug: `node scripts/build-debug.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the webplayer@0.1.2 build-debug script 'node scripts/build-debug.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the webplayer package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/build-debug.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs webplayer
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls webplayer
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people having this issue I found a fix.
All of our projects using firebase at our company where not able to get trough bitbucket pipelines or Docker containers. After some research it occurs that for some reason the npm package `promise-polyfill` doesn't exist anymore in the Node version 4.0.0 registry or something? We updated our container images to Node version 7.9.0 and everything works fine now!